Sitecore Experience Editor fails to open with error 'Connection to your rendering host failed with a Request Entity Too Large error.'
In our headless 10.2 site, pages that have a lot of content fail to load in Experience Editor, with the error Connection to your rendering host failed with a Request Entity Too Large error. Ensure the POST endpoint at URL https://mysite/api/editing/render has been enabled. The pages load fine in EE up until too many components are added (doesn't seem to matter which ones) but then break and cannot be opened in EE. They can however be opened in Preview and published to Edge, but authors are unable to do any editing.

I thought the issue was with Vercel's data limits - payload size is limited by Vercel to 4.5mb - but it's actually a setting in the source code limiting the payload size to only 2mb that breaks EE.
We found the answer in this blog post. Here's a summary:
The limit within the application is set in these two files:
src\pages\api\editing\data[key].ts
src\pages\api\editing\render.ts
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: {
      sizeLimit: '2mb',
    },
  },
};

I raised the limit from 2mb to 4mb in both files, and that resolved the EE error.
// Bump body size limit and disable response limit for Sitecore editor payloads
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: {
      sizeLimit: '4mb',
    },
    responseLimit: false,
  },
};

Because EE has a much bigger payload due to all the chrome placeholders on the page that make it editable, the payload limit is reached in EE sooner than with a published/previewed page.
